# 2 forms one submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to submit 2 forms with a one submit button, but it doesn't work I get only the second form, please help me
this is the code jQuery:

```
$('#BTN1').click(function() {
   $('#form1').submit();
   $('#form2').submit();
});
```

Comment: You can only submit one form per request

Comment: you can submit in 2 different targets

Comment: On which platform are you working?? I mean PHP or ASP.NET??

Comment: You can make a form with two tabs if this makes sense to your project.

Answer (score 1):

As is said in other answers, once the browser successfully submits a form, anything else happening on the page is lost when the new page loads.  So once form1 submits, everything that happens after that in your script is lost.

There are a few different ways you can handle this.  Since your tags say you're using jQuery, I you can easily use ajax to post the forms, wait until they're both done, and then switch to whatever new url you want.

```
$('#BTN1').click(function() {
   var form1done = false;
   var form2done = false;
   $.post( $('#form1').attr('action'), $('#form1').serialize())
       .done(function(r) { 
           form1done = true;
           if(form2done)
              location.assign('/target/location');
       }).fail(function() {
           // handle error
       });
   $.post(  $('#form2').attr('action'),  $('#form2').serialize())
       .done(function(r) {
            form2done = true;
            if(form1done)
                location.assign('/target/location');
       }).fail(function() {
            // handle error
       });
});
```

Look at the documentation for [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for more information.

That said, this is still going to be a clunky way to run a page.  You're probably better off either refactoring into a single form, or else going full ajax and just handling the results of the form submission in the same page.

A final option would be to change the `target` attribute of your forms so that they open in new windows.  That will allow both of them to complete submission.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because only one request will make it to the server. When your first form is being submitted, the second form interrupts it and starts.

You need to handle it in a different way. Do something with the first form first (send an AJAX request yourself instead of relying in the browser), wait till it's finished and then start with the second one.

Since AJAX requests are asynchronous you can even do them in parallel.

Comment: Unless the two forms are configured with a custom target or actually trigger AJAX requests, just waiting is not enough: if the first form is submitted successfully, the page will reload, and the JS will stop running.

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant that you have to do the submission yourself, by an AJAX request.

Comment: Right. In which case, of course, you don't need to wait, since the A in AJAX stands for "Asynchronous".

Comment: @Badrane Will you please upvote or accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

why not ajax submit the form...

```
$('#BTN1').click(function(e) {
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: UrlToPost,
          data: $('#form1').serialize(),
          success: function(msg) {
           }
})

$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: UrlToPost,
          data: $('#form2').serialize(),
          success: function(msg) {
           }
}) 
});
```

// Please note your BTN1 shouldn't be a type submit or it will refresh the page.. or you can put

```
e.preventDefault()
```

as the first line inside your click function.. to avoid referesh

Comment: While this is a sensible suggestion, you need to give a lot more detail about how this would work for this to be a useful answer.

Comment: @IMSoP agreed.. edited my answer :) .. Hope you remove the downvote

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but have an upvote anyway :)